# Request timeout in wagtail due to php issues

Tags: php, wagtail, litespeed

I'm using wagtail on a production and everything was working fine but suddenly something broke down. Now there is no possibility to edit content in this cms. For example, when I want to upload a picture for my content, there is no response from the server. After 2 minutes I have an error 500 with request timeout. I checked the logs and found something like this:

```
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099090 [INFO] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] Connection idle time: 121 while in state: 7 stream flag: 0x162000,close!
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099143 [NOTICE] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] Content len: 640710, Request line: 'POST /api/wagtail/cms/images/chooser/upload/ HTTP/1.1'
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099148 [INFO] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] Cookie len: 334, csrftoken=f3LAgViNjjziXy4BfkNmCn7YrbK0kjtFXLyyXY0QazSdOQR9muoXos5eou1MVHKd; sessionid=suajse6uompo5u58n6wpvgi3jrol6zel; token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgwNzA5NzU3LCJqdGkiOiJlZWI4ZGUzYmIwNjc0NjBkOWEyZjc1ZTI5ZDNkNGMwZCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjE0Nn0.LzbHdwJssivr_jOpWQb07681bFBT3klZWy-1uIHiL88
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099150 [NOTICE] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] Redirect: #1, URL: /wagtail/cms/imag
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099306 [INFO] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] HttpExtConnector state: 10, request body sent: 0, response body size: -2, response body sent:0, left in buffer: 0, attempts: 0.
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099312 [INFO] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] Lsapi connection state: 4, watching event: 25, respState: 0, m_iTotalPending:3592, m_iPacketLeft:0, m_iCurRespHeader:7, req sent for 121 seconds,Total processing time: 121.
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099375 [INFO] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] abort request..., code: 4 
2023-04-05 15:46:28.099378 [INFO] [2491587] [T0] [89.64.94.186:6001-H3:5ADBFD82AE1101B3-20#APVH_www.live.pocketsafe.se:443] Abort request processing by PID:2494544, kill: 1, begin time: 121, sent time: 121, req processed: 2
```

I have found several solutions to modify some config files of php.ini or lsws but the problem is I didn't setup the production server and I don't have root privileges and nobody working with me has it. How can I sort out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please ask you host to update their production LSWS 6.1 installation to the latest build.
It is a known bug, has been fixed.